# Check if app runs on Simulator

Tags: c#, mobile, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

How can I check if a WinRT app runs inside the simulator?

For Windows Phone I use following piece of code:

```
    Boolean isOnEmulator 
            = (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == DeviceType.Emulator);
```

But I cannot find the solution fot WinRT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
bool isRemote = Windows.System.RemoteDesktop.InteractiveSession.IsRemote;
```

it will return true if it is on Simulator else false.

Comment: What could be the cost of this error --> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in app.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.System.RemoteDesktop.IInteractiveSessionStatics'.